# Target specific submit button using bootstrap validator

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My form has two submit buttons, one submits the main form and the other one sends data using ajax. Can't figure out how to tell bootstrap validator that in this case we are using different submit button. And yes on that submit im using preventDefault();

```
$("#submitformat").click(function( event ) {
   $('#formid').bootstrapValidator({  // this id is correct
     message: 'This value is not valid',
     fields: {
        alias: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 6,
                    max: 30,
                    message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/,
                    message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number and underscore'
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
```

HTML button:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitformat" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Accordig to [Here](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/) you have to use **submitHandler** option on **bootstrapvalidator** to use it with ajax

*Taked from the link*

Using Ajax to Submit Form

In the case you want to use Ajax to submit the form and perform additional tasks after that, you can use submitHandler option.

Regard to our modal example, the following code shows how to:

Check if there is an account with given username and password by sending them to remote URL via an Ajax request
If yes, reload current page
Otherwise, show the message informing the account is not found

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
            $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {
                // The result is a JSON formatted by your back-end
                // I assume the format is as following:
                //  {
                //      valid: true,          // false if the account is not found
                //      username: 'Username', // null if the account is not found
                //  }
                if (result.valid == true || result.valid == 'true') {
                    // You can reload the current location
                    window.location.reload();

                    // Or use Javascript to update your page, such as showing the account name
                    // $('#welcome').html('Hello ' + result.username);
                } else {
                    // The account is not found
                    // Show the errors
                    $('#errors').html('The account is not found').removeClass('hide');

                    // Enable the submit buttons
                    $('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator('disableSubmitButtons', false);
                }
            }, 'json');
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

---

Plus this is not neccessary to overwrite **.click()** when the button have **sumbit** (type of the button)

Answer (score 0):

Validator probably doesn't care how the form was submitted. You may need to do something like this to detect which button was clicked:

```
if (event.target == $('#submitformat')) {
    ...
}
```